# How can I refactor my following nested swift if statements in the function below?

Tags: swift, refactoring

The following function does the job but I feel that I can better clean my code by refactoring the number of if statements below.

I want to set the value of `preferredGender` to either `female`, `male` or `both` depending on whether `preferMen` and `preferWomen` is set to either `true` or `false`.

```
func setUserDiscoveryPreferences(discoveryPrefs: [String : Any]){

    preferMen = discoveryPrefs["men"] as? Bool
    preferWomen = discoveryPrefs["women"] as? Bool


    if preferWomen == true && preferMen == true {

        preferredGender = "both"
    }

    if preferWomen == true && preferMen == false {

        preferredGender = "female"
    }

    if preferWomen == false && preferMen == true{

        preferredGender = "male"
    }

    if preferWomen == false && preferMen == false {

        preferredGender = ""
    }

}//end func
```

Comment: Note that your preferMen/preferWomen are *optionals.* If any of them is nil, none of the statements is executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont actually need to compare with true/false, so the first improvement you could make is this:

```
if preferWomen && preferMen {
    preferredGender = "both"
}

if preferWomen && !preferMen {
    preferredGender = "female"
}

if !preferWomen && preferMen {
    preferredGender = "male"
}

if !preferWomen && !preferMen {
    preferredGender = ""
}
```

For length if statements though it's generally better to use a switch statement

```
switch (preferWomen, preferMen) {
   case (true, true):
       preferredGender = "both"
   case (true, false):
       preferredGender = "women"
   case (false, true):
       preferredGender = "men"
   case (false, false):
       preferredGender = ""
}
```

Playground example

```
let preferMen = true
let preferWomen = false
var preferredGender = ""

switch (preferWomen, preferMen) {
case (true, true):
    preferredGender = "both"
case (true, false):
    preferredGender = "women"
case (false, true):
    preferredGender = "men"
case (false, false):
    preferredGender = ""
}

print(preferredGender)
```

> **Output:** men

Comment: I've added another improvement too

Comment: I would recommend `case (false, false):` instead of a default case, so that the compiler verifies that all cases are covered.

Comment: I've had to add a `default: break` case otherwise I get a `Switch must be exhaustive` error.

Comment: i had a default for the last case, but Martin R advised to change it, We have actually covered all cases, maybe because yours are optionals